# Ring of integers of a cyclotomic number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\omega$ be the primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity. Consider the number field $\mathbb Q(\omega)$. How to show that the ring of integers for this field is $\mathbb Z(\omega)$?

Also, find the discriminant of $\mathbb Z(\omega)/\mathbb Z$.

If $n$ is a prime, then finding the discriminant is easy using the concept of norm. But how to do it in a general case?

Comment: Do you know the technique of localization?

Comment: @Lubin No, I do not.

Answer (score 4):

This question was previously asked and answered on Math Overflow:

[Quick proof of the fact that the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}[\zeta_n]$ is $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17289/quick-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-ring-of-integers-of-q-zeta-n-is-z-zeta-n)

Alternatively, a proof [can be found here.](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntChapter7.pdf)